# Commit new Project in Solution to existing Repo

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2019, git-branch

I have an existing repo that includes several projects that I have been committing to.
I created a new project inside my VS 2019 solution and committed all my new files to my new branch called A.
After working on a different branch, & then checking out my branch A, I don't see my project inside my VS but it does exist on the local disk.

By just committing the new files inside my new project, does the project get included in the branch or do I have to do something else to include the project?
My new project inside VS shows 'Pending Add'.

Comment: This seems to have nothing at all to do with GitHub, and its relationship to Git is marginal at best (you'd have the same issue with any version control system).

Comment: understand your valid point. but at the same time I need to add my newly created project to my branch somehow. I am using git extensions as well.